# Devolver la posicion de una matriz

Tags: java, matrices

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

-Desarrolla un método que reciba una matriz de enteros y un número entero y que devuelva la fila y columna donde se encuentra el numero
entero. En caso de no estar en la matriz devolver fila -1 y columna -1.

**-Aqui pongo el metodo:**

```
public int[]  ejercicio31 (int[][] matriz, int numero){
    int[] posicion=new int[2];
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
            
            if(matriz[i][j]==numero){
                posicion[0]=i;
                posicion[1]=j;
            }
//            else {
//                posicion[0]=-1;
//                posicion[1]=-1;
//            } 
            }
            
           
        }

    
   return posicion;
}
```

**-Aquí el metodo de imprimir array:**

```
public void imprimirArray (int[] array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        
    }
   
}
```

**-Aquí pongo la matriz y el numero que envío:**

```
int [] posicion;
int numero=3;
int [][] matriz={{1,2,3,4}, 
                 {5,6,7,8},
                 {9,0,0,0}};
posicion=ej.ejercicio31(matriz, numero);
ej.imprimirArray(posicion);
```

Me devuelve la posicion correctamente pero el problema es que si pongo el else siempre me devuelve -1, El problema es que no se como devolver -1 si no lo encuentra y he probado más cosas pero no caigo en la solucion

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer y mejorando un poco tu función es que en el momento en que encuentres el valor devolver la posición sin necesidad de recorrer todos los valores.

```
public int[] ejercicio31(int[][] matriz, int numero) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {

            if (matriz[i][j] == numero) {
                // retorna la posición
                return new int[] {i, j};
            }
        }

    }
    // si no encuentra el elemento en el arreglo
    return new int[] {-1, -1};
}
```

Si termina de evaluar todos los elementos y no coincide con ninguno, devuelves -1, -1

Si lo que quieres es usar forzosamente el else necesitarías hacer un break para romper el ciclo for.

Comment: Benjamín Colin Gracias, no sabia que se pudiese devolver un return así, un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Respetando tu codigo en este caso podrias utilizar un `boolean` para evaluar si encontro o no el numero dentro de la matriz, a partir de ahí deberias evaluar si el `boolean` es `true`, si no asignas los valores correspondientes.

Ejemplo

```
public int[]  ejercicio31 (int[][] matriz, int numero){
    int[] posicion=new int[2];
    boolean existe = false;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
            
            if(matriz[i][j]==numero){
                posicion[0]=i;
                posicion[1]=j;
                existe = true; //Se pone en true si encuentra el numero
            }

         }
            
           
     }

    if(!existe){ // es lo mismo que decir if(existe == false)
       posicion[0]=-1;
       posicion[1]=-1;
    }

   return posicion;
}
```

Comment: Gracias!! pero no entiendo porque no vale mi else..

Comment: Lo que pasa es que los for siguen actuando a pesar de que el numero haya sido encontrado en la primera posición, suponiendo que el numero que pasaste es el 1 y que en la primera posición de la matriz también sea 1 entonces debe guardarse la posicion de la fila y columna, sin embargo el for tiene que seguir ejecutando y evaluando los demás elementos, en este caso ya no iría por la primera posición de la matriz sino por la segunda, este tiene que volver a evaluar si el numero que pasaste es el mismo que esta guardado en esa posición y como no lo es asigna el -1 y así con el resto de posiciones.

Comment: Si te ha servido mi respuesta a tu problema por favor puntuala en la palomita